# How can I get a members list in a voice channel from my bot?

Tags: python, django, discord.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
channel = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(677999369642836037)

async def members_list(request):
    curMembers = []
    for member in channel.members:
        curMembers.append(member)

    return render(request, "discordTool/discordTool.html", {
        'members_list': curMembers,
    })

client.run('my token')
```

This is my views.py of an app that supposes to show active members in a voice channel in my django site. However this doesn't work, can anyone help me or know a discord server about discord's API?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `channel = client.get_channel(677999369642836037)` sits inside the `on_ready` event, making it a local variable. It cannot be accessed outside the local coroutine.

You either need to make it a global variable, or move it to inside the `members_list` coroutine.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

async def members_list(request):
    channel = client.get_channel(677999369642836037)
    curMembers = []
    for member in channel.members:
        curMembers.append(member)

    return render(request, "discordTool/discordTool.html", {
        'members_list': curMembers,
    })

client.run('my token')
```

Comment: RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'django-main-thread'. 
We need to specify an event as @client.event but I am not sure it will work.